# unable to upload photo sometimes in facebook 3.0?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post image on `Facebook` using sdk 3.0, but I am facing some problems. If I close the app and reopens the app it always goes in else condition, then it goes in if condition. Do I need to save `session` or its already stored??

```
          Session mSession = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (mSession != null
            && mSession.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
        postPhoto();

    } else {

        if (mSession == null) {

            Log.d("Facebook", "Session null");
            mSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").build();
            Session.setActiveSession(mSession);

        }
        if (!mSession.isOpened()) {

            Log.d("Facebook", "Session not opened");

            Session.OpenRequest sessionRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(
                    this);

            sessionRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
            sessionRequest.setCallback(statuscallback);
            sessionRequest
                    .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
            mSession.openForPublish(sessionRequest);

        }

    }

StatusCallback statuscallback = new StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (session.isOpened()) {

                Log.d("Facebook", "Logged in");
                postPhoto();

            }
            if (session.isClosed()) {

                Log.d("Facebook", "Logged out");
            }
        }
    };



   @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);

            Log.d("Facebook", "onActivity Result");
        }
```

What if I need to logout the user??

I tried the following code onDestroy()

```
if (mSession.isOpened())
   mSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

whenever I open the app next time it always throws an error at this line if I use the above code in destroy method

```
mSession.openForPublish(sessionRequest);
```

Please help guys. Answers/Suggestion would be highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UiLifecycleHelper to help manage the active session throughout an Activity or Fragment lifecycle. Generally, all the session related data (access tokens, permissions, etc) are cached, and if you create a new Session(), it will use the cached data (unless you call closeAndClearTokenInformation, in which case it clears the cache). I would only call closeAndClearTokenInformation() on an explicit logout from the user, otherwise just call close() in onDestroy().

I would also avoid calling openForPublish. Always do openForRead, and then call session.getPermissions() to check if you have the necessary permissions, and then call requestNewPublishPermissions if you need more.

Comment: can u show me through code??  want to publish photo, then why need to `openForRead` instead of `openForPublish`

Comment: The sample apps that ship with the SDK are the best examples of how to use the UiLifecycleHelper, and the Scrumptious app (in SelectionFragment.java) there are examples on how to request publish permissions.

Comment: The reason you shouldn't call openForPublish directly is because it only works if the user has already given you basic (default) permissions.